# react-native-navigation: How to detect when user kills the app while being in a specific screen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using react-native-navigation v1. In my app I'm letting 2 users compete solving a number of questions each one has his turn. What I want is when the one user kills the app, the other user is notified. How I detects when the user kills the app in a specific screen.

I have searched react-native-navigation docs and issues and did not find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the navigation itself and, as far a I know, you cannot detect easily if the App is being closed in React Native. If it goes well, you could simply have some kind of heartbeat or disconnection detection settled up in the server you are using. As soon as you "detect" the App being closed send a notification to the other user.

Comment: What do you mean by "heartbeat or disconnection detection settled up in the server you are using"?

Comment: I supose that you are using a server. A hearthbeat is a "I'm here" message sent to the server in order to let it know that the device is still alive (they are also called "keep-alive"). It is used to keep track of unintended disconnections or, in other words, to know if a device is active.

Comment: You mean I repeatedly send a heartbeat within interval and when these heartbeats are no longer sent, this means the app has been killed?

Comment: Could also mean a disconnection (i. e. network issues). You should give certain time to reconnect before consider it as 'killed' in your app logic. Of course you should handle in a different way the case of the app going to background. This could be done through React Native's [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate)